# select multiple columns with dplyr having factor "No", "Yes" levels

Tags: select, dplyr, multiple-columns

I want to select all factor columns having two levels ("Yes", "No").
I want to use dpylr for this but, could not fix the problem.

```
    AB %>%
    select_if(.predicate = function(x) length(levels(x))==2 & unique(x) %in% c("No", "Yes"))
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data to use as a starting point? It's hard to help solve your question if you don't provide what `AB` is, even if its only 5-10 rows.

Answer (score 1):

`unique(x) %in% c('No','Yes')` returns a vector the same length as `unique(x)`, rather than a scalar. I think your better off using `setequal(x,c('No','Yes'))` as shown below:

```
library(dplyr)

# generate the dataframe with different factor levels
n<-100
no_yes       <- sample(c('No','Yes'),         n, replace = T) 
no_yes_maybe <- sample(c('No','Yes','Maybe'), n, replace = T)
no           <- sample(c('No'),               n, replace = T)
no_maybe     <- sample(c('No','Maybe'),       n, replace = T)

AB<-data.frame(
  no_yes, # only this column should get returned
  no_yes_maybe,
  no,
  no_maybe,
  stringsAsFactors = T
)%>%as.tbl

# function to return TRUE if column has only No/Yes factors. 
desired_levels <- c('No','Yes')
predicate_function <- function(x) setequal(levels(x),desired_levels)

# use dplyr to select columns with desired factor levels
AB%>%select_if(predicate_function)
```